# Skew and distort the Movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3

Here i am looking to skew and distort the Movie Clip dynamically.is this possible to do?

Does someone have a hint or example code for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a online web [Tuts](http://www.gotoandplay.it/_articles/2004/07/skew.php). just go through it.

Comment: you don't just add a link, make sure you tell what's in the tutorial.